# MFC static control not displayed correctly

Tags: visual-c++, static, mfc

I work on W10, using MFC. I try to display a static control which should be a simple white rectangle with simple text in it and see what I get :
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcUHU.jpg)
The little window with "english deutch, etc) should be under the new static and the left background image has been wrongly copied onto the left part of the static.
What am I doing wrong here? I use the following code:

```
void CMyStatic::Create(string content, int left, int top, int width, int height, CMyDlg* pdlg, UINT id)
{
    RECT rect = { left, top, left + width, top + height };
    CStatic::Create(content.c_str(), WS_CHILD | WS_VISIBLE, rect, pdlg, id);
    pdlg->GetDlgItem(id)->SetFont(pdlg->p_font, TRUE);
}
```

I expect the static to be topmost and non transparent

Comment: Please provide a better description. Which window is the static one? Where should it be, and what do you mean by "under the new static"? etc etc

Comment: Please show what you get vs. what you want.